# JSDoc syntax error when trying to deploy Firebase functions

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, eslint

I'm getting a `JSDoc syntax error` pointing to the first line of my JSDoc comment where it says `/**`. Not sure what else I need to fix.

```
/**
 * Gets any field value from a user's User collection.
 * @param {number} IDType 0 = uid, 1 = username.
 * @param {string} inputID the input ID, based on the IDType.
 * @param {string} desiredField the desired field value.
 * @returns {number, string, string} 1/0, error message, desired info.
 */
async function getUserInfo(
    IDType: number
    , inputID: string
    , desiredField: string
): Promise<[number, string, string]> {
 //...
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your return type is too complex, try with just `Promise` as [documentation](https://jsdoc.app/tags-returns.html) shows.

```js
/**
 * ...
 * @returns {Promise} 1/0, error message, desired info.
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

The type statement `{number, string, string}` on the `@returns` line is a syntax error.

As your function is `async`, the type should be defined as `{Promise<ResultType>}`. Additionally, because you are returning a tuple, you should be wrapping `number, string, string` in square brackets - `[number, string, string]`.

This results in a declaration of:

```js
/**
 * Gets any field value from a user's User collection.
 * @param {number} IDType 0 = uid, 1 = username.
 * @param {string} inputID the input ID, based on the IDType.
 * @param {string} desiredField the desired field value.
 * @returns {Promise<[number, string, string]>} 1/0, error message, desired info.
 */
async function getUserInfo(
    IDType: number
    , inputID: string
    , desiredField: string
): Promise<[number, string, string]> {
  //...
}
```

Alternatively, you can also define a type for your tuple and restrict the acceptable values for the `IDType` parameter:

```js
type IDType = 0 | 1;
type GetUserInfoResult = [ IDType, string, string ];

/**
 * Gets any field value from a user's User collection.
 * @param {IDType} typeOfInputID 0 = uid, 1 = username.
 * @param {string} inputID the input ID, of the given type.
 * @param {string} desiredField the desired field value.
 * @returns {Promise<GetUserInfoResult>} 1/0, error message, desired info.
 */
async function getUserInfo(
    typeOfInputID: IDType // renamed to prevent type conflict
    , inputID: string
    , desiredField: string
): Promise<GetUserInfoResult> {
  //...
}
```

This allows you to destructure the result and maintain the restrictive types:

```js
const result = await getUserInfo(1, 'exampleUser', 'displayName');
// type of result:        GetUserInfoResult

const [typeOfID, inputId, desiredField] = result;
// type for typeOfID:      IDType (accepts only 0 or 1)
// type for inputId:       string
// type for desiredField:  string
```

You can also destructure the result directly and still preserve the types:

```js
const [typeOfID, inputId, desiredField] = await getUserInfo(1, 'exampleUser', 'displayName');
// type for typeOfID:      IDType (accepts only 0 or 1)
// type for inputId:       string
// type for desiredField:  string
```

With the tuple type, you can also name each value in the tuple. These names are only used in your IDE and have no effect on the use of the value in JavaScript.

```js
type GetUserInfoResult = [ typeOfID: IDType, errorMsg: string, strValue: string ];

const result = await getUserInfo(1, 'exampleUser', 'displayName');
result[0] // type shows as "IDType (typeOfID)"
result[1] // type shows as "string (errorMsg)"
result[2] // type shows as "string (strValue)"

const [typeOfID, inputId, desiredField] = result;
// type for typeOfID shows as "IDType"
// type for inputId shows as "string"
// type for desiredField shows as "string"
```

Answer (score -1):

Just install JSDoc Lint... while three return values appear strange to me:

```
@returns {number, string, string} 1/0, error message, desired info.
```

And I'm probably right, because the [documentation](https://jsdoc.app/tags-returns.html) doesn't use any comma.

```
@returns {number|string} 1/0, error message or desired info.
```